# Registro não é atualizado no banco de dados

Tags: php, apache, firebird

Tenho uma aplicação que pega o conteúdo de determinado site e compara se está diferente do atual comparando com o registro no banco de dados e envia um e-mail que teve uma alteração, além de atualizar no banco de dados com o conteúdo novo para ser utilizado na próxima verificação.

Estava funcionando corretamente o recurso, porém agora parou de vez.

Mas não foi a primeira vez que ocorreu esse problema, tive que colocar um `ibase_commit` para atualizar corretamente no banco. E tem a ver com o método abaixo, já que passei uma String para teste diretamente na chamada do método e não foi atualizado o registro e o método é sempre chamado já que coloquei um `echo 'ok'` e retornou no CMD.

Segue a função do Controller:

```
    public function update($codigo, $conteudo){

        $connect = OpenConnection();    

        $query = ibase_query($connect, "UPDATE CAD_SITES SET CONTEUDO = ?, DATA_ENVIO_EMAIL = ?, HORA_ENVIO_EMAIL = ? WHERE CODIGO = ?", 'Teste', date('d-m-Y'), date('G:i:s'), $codigo);
        $result = false;

        if ($query){
            $result = ibase_commit($connect);
            if($result){
              echo "Alterou";
            } else {
              echo "Não alterou";  
            }
        }

        if (ibase_errmsg()){
            $result = '[ERRO] '.ibase_errmsg();
        }

        return $result;         

    }
```

Comment: Pelo jeito o auto commit do banco está desligado.

Comment: E como posso ligar? E não poderia funcionar com o `ibase_commit` mesmo que no banco estivesse desligado?

Comment: Sim deveria funcionar, teste se o `ibase_commit($connect);` retorna true.

Comment: Retorna true a condição, vou alterar o código acima com ela.

Comment: Tirei o update da data e da hora e funcionou, agora resta saber como atualizar a data e a hora da maneira correta.

Comment: Então, passe a data como `date('Y-m-d');`